# Magento reading config data

Tags: magento

I am trying to read config data for a custom module to enable or disable it based on the config setting. I am trying to read the config data in an [Observer](http://pastebin.com/WnkWXbwG) like this : `$module_state = Mage::helper('stopcheckout')->moduleActive();` and here is my [helper](http://pastebin.com/0KkxDvF7). My observer gets called when ever a product is added to cart. But i get a blank page when i try to read the config data with the above snipped of code. Here are the [config.xml](http://pastebin.com/VTBpbrpW) and [system.xml](http://pastebin.com/cUiXVFQt) files. Where am i going wrong? Thanks.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Your helper method is not correct, as I'm sure you've guessed :-)

Try this:

```
<?php
class Foostor_Stopcheckout_Helper_Data extends Mage_Core_Helper_Abstract
{
    /**
     * Check if the extension has been disabled in the system configuration
     */
    public function moduleActive()
    {
        return ! (bool) Mage::getStoreConfigFlag('catalog/stopcheckout/disable_ext');
    }
}
```

The `getStoreConfigFlag()` method always returns a boolean. It evaluates the strings "false" and "0" as `false`, so this is appropriate because the `adminhtml/system_config_source_yesno` source model uses 1 and 0 as the stored values.

The parameter that is passed for values set via system.xml fields will always have three parts: one for the `<sections>` node, one for the `<groups>` node, and one for the `<fields>` node.